# Change text color of a datepicker dialog in a webview

Tags: android, android-webview, android-alertdialog, android-datepicker

I need to change the color of the `Confirm` / `Cancel` buttons of a date picker in a `WebView`.
Right now they appear white on white background, so I just do not see them.

I read that date picker dialogs in a WebView are native android dialog, so this is what I tried right now without success (the text color is still white):

First of all, I added a style to the WebView in the layout file:

```
<WebView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="@style/dialogTheme" />
```

In my `styles.xml` file I added this style:

```
<style name="dialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#00397F</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">#ff0000</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ff0000</item>
</style>
```

I tried many combinations of these configs, nothing changed.

Comment: Hello @Giacomo, did you find a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

This should solve:

On your `styles.xml` file add this:

```
  <style name="Widget.Button" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/design_default_color_primary</item>
  </style>
```